# Vuelidate $each: How can I validate a nested collection?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I am having a really hard time trying to grasp the likely elementary concept(s). I am passing a `location` in as a prop. It has a json column to store `additionalAttributes`. It looks something like this:

```
    "additionalProperties": [
        {
            "integrations": [
                {
                    "exampleVendor": {
                        "locationId": 123,
                        "positionId": 456
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "",
    "updatedAt": "",
    ...
```

The above is what I've hard-coded into my database (Postgres) to attempt to mock what the data will look like when it comes back.

I am working from the [validate collections](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation) portion of the vuelidate documentation.

Here is what I am using to attempt to create the validation rule:

```
validations: {
      location: {
        additionalProperties: {
          $each: {
            integrations: {
              $each: {
                exampleVendor: {
                  locationId: {required},
                  positionId: {required},
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  },
```

In my template, I'm trying to connect the validations like this:

```
<select id="my-id" 
    name="my-id" 
    class="py-3 px-3 mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base sm:text-sm rounded-md" 
    v-if="locations"
    v-model.trim="$v.location.additionalProperties[0].integrations[0].exampleVendor.locationId.$model" 
    :class="[$v.location.additionalProperties[0].integrations[0].exampleVendor.locationId.$error ? 
    'focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 border-red-300' : 'focus:ring-gray-400 focus:border-gray-400 border-gray-300',]"
>
...
</select>
```

I've been working with this component for quite a while and have [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604975/vue-js-how-can-i-update-an-array-of-objects/66605051#66605051) a really silly question.

I am also concerned that by setting such a rigid path `additionalProperties[0].integrations[0]` is really bad.

I fear this one isn't too far behind but it's time to ask for some advice. Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

@tony19 made an excellent call about why the array if only the first value is being used. Perhaps there is a better way to do what I'm doing; here is a wider view of what the data in my database *could* look like. It has additional properties now beyond just integrations. For now, I'm only focused on that though.

```
"additionalProperties": [
        {
            "integrations": [
                {
                    "exampleVendor": {
                        "locationId": 123,
                        "positionId": 456
                    },
                    "anotherVendor": {
                        "foo": "abc",
                        "bar": "def"
                    },
                    "someOtherVendor": {
                        "thing": "value"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "anotherAttribute: {
                "one": "two"
            },
            "possibleAttributes": [...]
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things I've learned while working through this. One of the more important being how to troubleshoot what vuelidate thought it was getting.

I created an `change` handler to provide insight to what the `$model` value was. Here is an example:

```
<select @change="onChange"...">...</select>


...

// start with what I know to be true.
onChange() {
    console.log($v.location.additionalProperties);
}
```

Using the above object structure, I'd then move into the object until I ended up with this:

```
console.log($v.location.additionalProperties.$each[0].integrations.$each[0]. exampleVendor.locationId.$model; // 12345
```

Now that I had the "path" to the model, I could update my `<select>` element:

```
<select id="my-locationId" name="my-locationId" class="py-3 px-3 mt-1 block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base sm:text-sm rounded-md" 
    v-model.trim="$v.location.additionalProperties.$each[0].integrations .$each[0].exampleVendor.locationId.$model"
    :class="[
             $v.location.additionalProperties.$each[0].integrations.$each[0].exampleVendor.locationId.$error
                        ? 'focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 border-red-300'
                        : 'focus:ring-gray-400 focus:border-gray-400 border-gray-300',
                    ]"
    >
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select</option>
    <option
        v-for="location in myLocations"
        :key="location.id"
        :value="location.id"
    >
        {{ location.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now that the nested path was collecting/setting the data, I could set up the validation rules:

```
...

data: () => ({...}),

validations: {
  location: {
      additionalProperties: {
        $each: {
          integrations: {
            $each: {
              exampleVendor: {
                locationId: { required },
                positionId: { required },
              },
            },
          },
        },
     },
  },
},

...

methods: {
  async save() {
      this.$v.$touch();

      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.errors = true;
      } else {
        try {
          const params = {
            location: this.location, // location is passed in as props
            method: this.location.id ? "PATCH" : "POST",
          };

          console.log('params: ', params);  // {...}

          // Save to vuex or ??
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('there was an error:', error);
        }
      }
    },
}
```

Hope this helps someone else - it wasn't super straight forward & I'm sure there is a more effective way, but this ended up working for me.

**EDIT 2**

Please be sure to follow @tony19's suggested answer as well. The solution provided removes the "rigidity" I was speaking about in my question.

Comment: Why do you need the arrays if you're only going to access the first element?

Comment: Great question! Perhaps there is a more direct approach. I've added an EDIT to my question to show how the `additionalProperties` could end up looking like and why I felt I needed the array(s). I'd be stoked to hear what you think!

Comment: In the same vibe as your question, I really don't like this: `$v.location.additionalProperties.$each[0].integrations.$each[0].exampleVendor.` It seems very rigid. I would much rather: `$v.location.additionalProperties.integrations.$each.exampleVendor.foo...`
Given that `additionalProperties` is an array (or maybe that's the issue -- it doesn't need it IDK)

Answer (score 1):

As you commented it's possible to have more array values in `additionalProperties` and `integrations`, it makes more sense to *iterate* those properties rather than hard-coding access to the first element only.

The [Vuelidate docs for collections you linked](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation) shows iterating the array with `$each.$iter`, so I would use `<template v-for="ARRAY.$each.$iter">` for each level of nesting:

```html
<template v-for="(addtlProperty, i) in $v.location.additionalProperties.$each.$iter">
  <template v-for="(integration, j) in addtlProperty.integrations.$each.$iter">
    <select
      :key="`${i}-${j}`"
      v-model.trim="integration.exampleVendor.locationId.$model"
      :class="[
        integration.exampleVendor.locationId.$error
          ? 'focus:ring-red-500 focus:border-red-500 border-red-300'
          : 'focus:ring-gray-400 focus:border-gray-400 border-gray-300',
      ]"
    >
    ...
    </select>
  </template>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/validating-nested-collections-in-vuelidate-q0fiv?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue:49-761)

Comment: WOW! This is so great. Thank you for sharing this - *exactly* the push I needed to get set straight. I wish there was a way I could select this as the answer too.